# Marble Runs Expected Value Question - Linearity of Expectation

Tags: probability, statistics

You repeatedly draw marbles from a bag containing 50 red and 50 blue marbles until there are no more marbles left, recording the order of red and blue marbles drawn. You then count the number of "runs," where a run is defined as any number of consecutive marbles of the same color. For example, RBBRRRBRR contains 5 runs. What is the expected number of runs that you observe?

I'm having a tough time solving this. I know that we need to use linearity of expectation, so I'm thinking at every point theres a 1/2 chance the run changes in which we +1, or 1/2 we leave it the same in which we +0. But I don't think I'm taking into account that the amount of marbles is reducing, but I'm not sure because I thought linearity of exception didn't take into consideration dependent events? Idk im confused

Comment: Linearity of expectation applies even when the r.v's are not independent

Comment: Without replacement, the probability at each point is not exactly $\frac12$ though marginally it is constant between points (though remember that the number of points between marbles is not exactly $100$ and that you may need to think about the end points).

Comment: I suggest:  work this out carefully for a small number of marbles (like $4$) where you can write out all the cases.  That way you might hope to avoid small errors in the calculation.

Comment: Linearity of expectation is helpful, but the analysis seems unfortunately way more complicated than the simple case where each color can occur next with $p=1/2$. For example, the expected value for a new ball to start a new run is not $1/2$, though for small values of balls it seems constant from column to column (except the first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to condition on what has already happened once the process has started, think of the sequence of marbles as being chosen all at once.

For any pair of adjacent positions in the sequence, every ordered pair of different marbles is equally likely to appear there. There are $100\times99$ such pairs, and $100\times50$ of them include one marble of each color, so the probability that the run changes at this position is $50/99$. Then by linearity of expectation, the expected number of run changes is $50$, so the expected number of runs is $51$.

Comment: Easily extended with $n$ balls of each colour to an expected number of runs of $n+1$, which is easily checked for small $n$

Comment: Ah I see. However, doesn’t the amount of ordered pair based on how many pervious marbles have been drawn. So like i.e. for the first 2, it makes sense. However now that marbles have been drawn how can the total amount of pairs be 100 x 99

Comment: The marbles will come out in some order, and all orders are equally likely. If we consider an arbitrary position in the sequence, every marble (or pair of marbles) is equally likely to appear there. The pairs at different positions are not independent, but linearity of expectation doesn't require independence.